# .htaccess redirect subdomain to folder with masking

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Is it possible to do something like this :

redirect: **subdomain.domain.com** to **subdomain.domain.com/user/login** without showing "/user/login/"
so it will display the login page on the main subdomain without showing "/user/login/" on address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. Just put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^/?$ /user/login/ [L]
```

Comment: once I did that it makes the page 404 not found and it shows http://subdomain.domain.com/user/login on address bar

Comment: This rule is not doing any URL redirect but you may have other rules in this .htaccess. Can you post your complete .htaccess?